# Vertically merge columns from different data frames and add new column with value corresponding to data frame originated from

Tags: r

I have four simple data frames (each corresponding to a different type of crop) and each has one column with a value of plant biomass. I want to merge these data frames so that I end up with one data frame that has two columns: one with the concatenated plant biomass values, and the second column with a factor value indicating what data frame it originated from.

Here's a replication of the first three rows of each of the data frames.

```
id <- seq(1:3)
fallow_ndvi <- c(0.1547380, 0.2494604, 0.2277472)
fallow_df <- data.frame(id, fallow_ndvi)

wheat_ndvi <- c(0.5137470, 0.1146732, 0.5774466)
wheat_df <- data.frame(id, wheat_ndvi)

date_ndvi <- c(0.1547380, 0.2494604, 0.2277472)
date_df <- data.frame(id, date_ndvi)

lettuce_ndvi <- c(0.5036867, 0.4597749, 0.5764071)
lettuce_df <- data.frame(id, lettuce_ndvi)
```

I should note that each dataframe has a different number of rows and the ID value is insignificant, (though they are present in the datasets as they are automatically generated earlier in my workflow.

Expected Output:

```
expected_output <-c(fallow_ndvi, wheat_ndvi, date_ndvi, lettuce_ndvi)
expected_output_df <- data.frame(expected_output)

fallow_vector <- rep('fallow_ndvi', each = 3)
wheat_vector <- rep('wheat_ndvi', each = 3)
date_vector <- rep('date_ndvi', each = 3)
lettuce_vector <- rep('lettuce_ndvi', each = 3)

originating_df_vector <- c(fallow_vector, wheat_vector, date_vector, lettuce_vector)


expected_output_df[ ,'field_category'] <- originating_df_vector

names(expected_output_df) <- c('NDVI', 'field_type')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
l <- list(fallow_df, wheat_df, date_df, lettuce_df) # or mget(ls(pattern = "_df")) if necessary
map(l,select,-id) %>% bind_cols %>% gather(field_type,NDVI)
#      field_type      NDVI
# 1   fallow_ndvi 0.1547380
# 2   fallow_ndvi 0.2494604
# 3   fallow_ndvi 0.2277472
# 4    wheat_ndvi 0.5137470
# 5    wheat_ndvi 0.1146732
# 6    wheat_ndvi 0.5774466
# 7     date_ndvi 0.1547380
# 8     date_ndvi 0.2494604
# 9     date_ndvi 0.2277472
# 10 lettuce_ndvi 0.5036867
# 11 lettuce_ndvi 0.4597749
# 12 lettuce_ndvi 0.5764071
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::bind_rows()` or even `rbind()` in Base R. You can specify the data frame name in the data frames themselves, or can use the `.id` argument in `dplyr::bind_rows()` and have it auto generate it for you, although it won't be as explicit as if you provide it yourself.

```
library(dplyr)
id <- seq(1:3)
fallow_ndvi <- c(0.1547380, 0.2494604, 0.2277472)
fallow_df <- data.frame(id, df = "fallow", ndvi = fallow_ndvi, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

wheat_ndvi <- c(0.5137470, 0.1146732, 0.5774466)
wheat_df <- data.frame(id, df = "wheat", ndvi = wheat_ndvi, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

date_ndvi <- c(0.1547380, 0.2494604, 0.2277472)
date_df <- data.frame(id, df = "date", ndvi = date_ndvi, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lettuce_ndvi <- c(0.5036867, 0.4597749, 0.5764071)
lettuce_df <- data.frame(id, df = "lettuce", ndvi = lettuce_ndvi, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

combined_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(fallow_df
                                , wheat_df
                                , date_df
                                , lettuce_df)
combined_df
# id      df      ndvi
# 1   fallow 0.1547380
# 1   fallow 0.2494604
# 1   fallow 0.2277472
# 2    wheat 0.5137470
# 2    wheat 0.1146732
# 2    wheat 0.5774466
# 3     date 0.1547380
# 3     date 0.2494604
# 3     date 0.2277472
# 4  lettuce 0.5036867
# 4  lettuce 0.4597749
# 4  lettuce 0.5764071
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern = "_df")) %>% 
      map_df(~ .x %>% 
                  select(matches("ndvi")) %>% 
                  mutate(field_type = names(.)) %>% 
                  select(NDVI = 1, field_type))
#      NDVI   field_type
#1  0.1547380    date_ndvi
#2  0.2494604    date_ndvi
#3  0.2277472    date_ndvi
#4  0.1547380  fallow_ndvi
#5  0.2494604  fallow_ndvi
#6  0.2277472  fallow_ndvi
#7  0.5036867 lettuce_ndvi
#8  0.4597749 lettuce_ndvi
#9  0.5764071 lettuce_ndvi
#10 0.5137470   wheat_ndvi
#11 0.1146732   wheat_ndvi
#12 0.5774466   wheat_ndvi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 stack(Reduce(merge,mget(ls(pattern = "_df")))[-1])
      values          ind
1  0.1547380    date_ndvi
2  0.2494604    date_ndvi
3  0.2277472    date_ndvi
4  0.1547380  fallow_ndvi
5  0.2494604  fallow_ndvi
6  0.2277472  fallow_ndvi
7  0.5036867 lettuce_ndvi
8  0.4597749 lettuce_ndvi
9  0.5764071 lettuce_ndvi
10 0.5137470   wheat_ndvi
11 0.1146732   wheat_ndvi
12 0.5774466   wheat_ndvi
```

Since you said `id` is not important, we can drop it:

```
stack(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "_df")),"[[",2))
      values        ind
1  0.1547380    date_df
2  0.2494604    date_df
3  0.2277472    date_df
4  0.1547380  fallow_df
5  0.2494604  fallow_df
6  0.2277472  fallow_df
7  0.5036867 lettuce_df
8  0.4597749 lettuce_df
9  0.5764071 lettuce_df
10 0.5137470   wheat_df
11 0.1146732   wheat_df
12 0.5774466   wheat_df
```